# Working Private Key Pair Stopped Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, putty, winscp

After several days of working on a Flask webapp when I tried using Putty and WinSCP to connect to my server I got the following error message:

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: public key).

I then launched a new EC2 instance and after getting a basic web app and running and logging out of Putty and trying to get back in the same thing happened.

Perfectly good key pair which works influentially suddenly stops working.

Any thoughts on what the problem might be?

Comment: Definitely connecting to correct host? With correct user name? With correct private key? No chance you deleted authorized_keys from the instance's .ssh folder? Anything useful visible in the EC2 console log?

Comment: Thanks for helping. 

Host/user name/ private key are correct. The same as when it previously worked.  

Don't think I deleted any authorized_keys. Did change some ownership of directories within the structure as I'm using an Ubuntu machine. 

Nothing useful in the console log.

Comment: User name is ubuntu or whatever, yes? You're not accidentally using ec2-user. If connecting by IP, double-check the IP for the instance (no chance that the IP changed?) Reboot make any difference?

Comment: username is ubuntu. using the static public IP created by AWS.

When I was able to SSH i didn't have root permission as would be typical with the user being ubuntu

Comment: A common cause for this is doing something you shouldn't be, possibly involving `chmod -R ...`.

Comment: @sqlbot Thanks for all of the help. 

Seems like your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description regarding permission changes I think @sqlbot has the right answer here. If you've recursively changed permissions or ownership within a user directory (`chmod -R 777 /home/someuser` or something similar) then you may have accidentally changed the permissions of `/home/someuser/.ssh/authorized_keys` afterwhich the public keys associated with this user will no longer be honored.

These are the correct permissions for `.ssh` and `.ssh/authorized_keys`:

```
chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Unfortunately if you can't access the instance you won't be able to reset them at this point.

Comment: Much appreciated. 

Couldn't access the previous instance but it seems like this is the fix.

Comment: Great. Can you accept the answer so others can find it?

Comment: Does anything else have to be done after running these `chmod` commands? I've tried this but still can't connect even though the `authorized_keys` file looks perfectly intact.

Comment: To be clear, you're already on the server -- correct? How are you getting access from your client host to the server if ssh isn't working?